# Android Status Notifications

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, status

I have created a BackgroundService class which extends Service class.

I have a Timer which keeps track of the duration between checks.  In the onCreate method I set it for 10 seconds, so the behavior I'm expecting is that it sends a status notification message every 10 seconds.  The issue I'm having is that every 10 seconds, I hear the status notification "sound" as I enabled it, but I do not see the text reminder on the top of the screen, which only appears on the first notification service alert.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

I attached a good deal of source for this class below: Thanks in Advance!

private Timer timer;

```
private TimerTask updateTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer task doing work!");   

        // Process junk here:
        sendNotification("Please leave in 5 min!!!");
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Background Service creating");

    timer = new Timer("DurationTimer");
    timer.schedule(updateTask, 1000L, 10*1000L);
}

public void sendNotification(CharSequence message)
{
    // Execute Check and Notify
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    int icon = R.drawable.simon;
    CharSequence tickerText = message;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "LEAVE NOW!";
    CharSequence contentText = "LEAVE NOW!!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    int HELLO_ID = 1;
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: caan u tell me where u added the accepted code  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of contentText with each iteration.

Example:

```
CharSequence contentText = "LEAVE NOW!! " + System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I think you will find that the message text changes constantly because you already have a Notification with the same ID as the Notification you wish to send. So what happens is that the text is simply changed.

Another way:

```
mNotificationManager.clear(HELLO_ID);
```

Do that before you create the new Notification.

Comment: I tried changing the contentText, contentTitle and HELLO_ID values by using the System.currentTimeMillis() separately, but it didn't solve the issue of the notification text not showing up the second time around.  Do you know of anything else that may cause this?  Thanks.

Comment: New section added to answer body.

Comment: I used mNotificationManager.cancel(HELLO_ID), which worked.  Thanks!